# I can't run my expo project since I updated expo-sdk

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

**When I try to run my expo project I get this message:**

```
D:\React\myproject>npm start

> start
> expo start

Starting project at D:\React\myproject
Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?
```

**If I run npm install i get this:**

```
D:\React\myproject>npm install
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/

up to date, audited 940 packages in 4s

18 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

12 vulnerabilities (6 low, 6 moderate)

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

**And this is what I get when I run `npm audit`:**

```
 D:\React\myproject>npm audit
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
# npm audit report

node-fetch  =0.22.0-rc
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios
          Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
          node_modules/react-native
          node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-native
        metro-config  =0.3.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of xmldom
  node_modules/plist
    @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of plist
    Depends on vulnerable versions of xcode
    node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios
      react-native  =0.22.0-rc
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios
      Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
      node_modules/react-native
      node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-native
        @react-native-community/cli  *
        Depends on vulnerable versions of metro
        Depends on vulnerable versions of react-native
        node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
    simple-plist  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of plist
    node_modules/simple-plist
      xcode  >=0.8.3
      Depends on vulnerable versions of simple-plist
      node_modules/xcode

12 vulnerabilities (6 low, 6 moderate)

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

**This happens since I tried to update expo sdk, but I don't know what I did wrong. Can someone help me with this?**

Comment: Did you run `npm install` ?

Comment: Yes, im updating the post now.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/tls-test/issues/1 (The issues listed after the tls 1.2 notice are your problem though... The notice doesn't block installation today.)

Answer (score 36):

Run `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Some computers are still running with `http://registry.npmjs.org/` which is not going to be allowed anymore for security reasons.

Comment: Run `npm config get registry` first to see what your current config is and make sure it changed with the above command.

Comment: I love how none of these commands are listed in the official github blog page which the error message redirects people: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/ Thanks for the info guys!

Answer (score 2):

You may try adding a .npmrc file and update the repo allocation under the user\xxx directory.
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/